# ChakraUI useBreakpoints cause rerender on Gatsby

Tags: gatsby, chakra-ui

I'm struggling with a website flash at start caused by chakra ui rerender. The root cause is easily reproducible with simple:

```
const breakpoint = useBreakpoint({ ssr: true });
console.log(breakpoint);
```

Even on Chakra UI gatsby's starter:
https://github.com/chakra-ui/gatsby-starter-chakra-ui-ts

console.log returns

```
undefined
xl
```

Which obviously cause rerender.

The same problem applies to everything which relies on breakpoints like: `<Show>` component or `useBreakpointValue()` hook.

Is it possible to mitigate that issue? It impacts overall website experience and it occurse at every subpage.